# Why does this give me a circular reference error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've hacked together this bit of code which throws an error when run in React / Next.js:

```
const myArray = ["a","b","c"];

myArray.forEach((item, index, array) => {
  if(item === "b") {
    array[index] = <span>b</span>;
  }
});

console.log(${JSON.stringify(myArray, null, 2)}); // Circular error
```

The above console.log throws this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property '_context' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'Provider' closes the circle
```

Although it renders in the browser OK, the console.log has identified a deeper issue causing downstream issues.

Why is this a circular structure?

Comment: How is this proper Javascript: `console.log(${JSON.stringify(myArray, null, 2)});`?

Comment: JSX............

Comment: OK, I'll try to train myself to ignore all JSX questions in the future.  Kind of hard when one little tag is the only possible indicator (I see you added text to the question about that since).

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce that error either, but there is a few things that I can guess:

Circular structure is a structure that references the parent structure, so I think that changing the original array may create duplicate references for the same structure. I would suggest you to use .map instead:

```
let myArray = ["a", "b", "c"];

myArray = myArray.map((item) => (item === "b" ? <span>b</span> : item));

console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray, null, 2));
```

That should work, but, going further, i have seen problems with those "self mapping" due to the way javascript reference types works. I suggest to use a new constant:

```
const myArray = ["a", "b", "c"];

const myArrayMap = myArray.map((item) =>
  item === "b" ? <span>b</span> : item
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(myArrayMap, null, 2));
```

Comment: I put in tags, but forgot to add in question - this is in React and Next.js...